# Tensorflow queues and multi threads : how to use the data API

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, parallel-processing, queue, timeline

I'm currently trying to implement a **Tensorflow pipeline**. Indeed i want to load the data with my CPU and use my GPU to run the graph **at the same time**. In order to understand better what is happening, i've created a very simple convolutionnal network :

```
import os
import h5py
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
sess= tf.InteractiveSession()
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import time



t1 = time.time()

class generator:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def __call__(self):
        with h5py.File(self.file, 'r') as hf:
            for im in hf["data"]:
                yield tuple(im)


dataset = tf.data.Dataset().from_generator(generator('file.h5'),
                                           output_types= tf.float32,
                                           output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None,4,128,128,3])))



dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=1000)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(10)


iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
e1 = iter.get_next()
e1 = tf.reshape(e1, (-1, 128, 128, 3))

with tf.device('gpu'):
    output = tf.layers.conv2d(e1[:150],200,(5,5))
    output = tf.layers.conv2d(output,50,(5,5))
    output = tf.layers.conv2d(output, 50, (5, 5))
    output = tf.layers.conv2d(output, 25, (5, 5))



with tf.Session() as sess:
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.intra_op_parallelism_threads = 2
    tf.Session(config=config)
    options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(iter.initializer)
    for i in range(10):
        a = sess.run(output, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
        print('done')
        fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
        chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()

    with open('timeline_01.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(chrome_trace)

t2= time.time()
print('TIME', t2-t1)
```

And i don't understand the results :

[image: Timeline]

- first it seems that the number of threads doesn't matter on the time i spend to run the whole code. (68 seconds) Indeed when i comment the following lines :

  ```
  config = tf.ConfigProto()
  config.intra_op_parallelism_threads = 2
  tf.Session(config=config)
  ```

it is still the same...

- second, why are the GPU and the CPU not used at the same time ? Am i doing something wrong ?

If someone can help me, it would be very nice to him because i've already spend two days on this issue.

Thanks a lot for your help